# Vuetify v-row and v-col taking up less space than their child elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my component, I laid everything out according to this hierarchy; v-container > v-row > v-col > v-app-bar.

However, the v-row doesn't grow to take up the same amount of space as it's child components:

[image: v-row]

And the v-col doesn't take up any space at all:

[image: v-col]

[image: v-app-bar]

I thought that, by default, the parent element would naturally stretch to take up the same amount of space as its child elements? This certainly seems to be the case from the video tutorials I've watched.

There's nothing in the [v-col API docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/) or elsewhere in the Vuetify docs to explain this behaviour.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening?

My code is below. I tried adding a min-h-64 to the v-row but that made no difference.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="d-flex">
          <v-app-bar class="bg-teal">
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-tool-bar-title class="mx-auto"
              >Vuetify Dashboard</v-tool-bar-title
            >
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn variant="elevated" class="mr-2" color="primary">Home</v-btn>
            <v-btn variant="elevated" class="mr-5" color="primary">About</v-btn>
          </v-app-bar>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="h-screen">
        <v-col class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
          <v-card width="400" class="mx-auto">
            <v-card-title class="my-5">
              <h1 class="display-1">Login</h1>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-form>
                <v-text-field
                  label="Username"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
                />
                <v-text-field
                  :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                  label="Password"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
                  :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                  @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                />
              </v-form>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn class="register bg-teal" elevation="2" variant="elevated"
                >Register</v-btn
              >
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn class="login" color="primary" elevation="2" variant="flat"
                >Login</v-btn
              >
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-footer app class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="bg-teal d-flex w-100 align-center px-4 mx-0">
              <strong>Get connected with us on social networks!</strong>

              <v-spacer></v-spacer>

              <v-btn
                v-for="icon in icons"
                :key="icon"
                class="mx-4"
                :icon="icon"
                variant="plain"
                size="small"
              ></v-btn>
            </div>

            <div class="px-4 py-2 bg-black text-center w-100">
              {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} — <strong>Vuetify</strong>
            </div>
          </v-footer>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {},

  data: () => ({
    showPassword: false,
  }),
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `v-app-bar` is part of the [application layout](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/), it is intended to be aligned by `v-app`, not manually as a column in `v-container` - it does not make sense to think of the app bar as column content.

The intended layout would be:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar class="bg-teal">
    ...
  </v-app-bar>
  <v-main>
    <v-container fluid>
      ...
    </v-container>
  </v-main>
</v-app>
```